# Writing back tuple to excel conditionally(only values > 0)

Tags: tuples, cplex, opl

I am trying to write a tuple back to excel. However since many of the values are 0 for Xbiedt a combination of the b,i,e,d and t makes it more than 1,300,000 rows of output. Excel cannot hanlde that many rows. Hence I want to restrict the output t only values that have Xbiedt > 0. Below is the part of the code.

```
tuple SolXbiedt{
int b;
int i;
int e;
int d;
int t;
float x_value;
}


{SolXbiedt} solXbiedt    = {<b,i,e,d,t, Xbiedt[b][i][e][d][t] > | b in PitBlocks, i in PitExits, e in DumpEntries, d in DumpBlocks, t in TimePeriods};
```

Looking forward for help please.

In the dat file I have the following line

```
solXbiedt to SheetWrite(sheet,"Result!H3:M4000000");
```

When the model is run the error I get is as below:
Exception from IBM ILOG Concert: Excel range is unknown.

I also tried changing the dat file to as below, reducing the limit to within 1 million rows in Excel.

```
solXbiedt to SheetWrite(sheet,"Result!H3:M1000000");
```

Then I get the following :
Exception from IBM ILOG Concert: excel: range size is not wide enough for set of tuples: missing rows.

Answer (score 0):

Let me give you 2 examples for your 2 questions.

1) First you want to store only some part of the results.

Suppose you want to know which integer values in a range can be divided by 3. You may write

```
range r=1..10;


dvar int y[r];
dvar int z[r] in 0..2;

minimize sum(i in r) z[i];
subject to
{
forall(i in r) i==3*y[i]+z[i];
}

{int} x={i | i in r:z[i]==0};
execute
{
writeln(z);
writeln(x);
}
```

which gives

```
[1 2 0 1 2 0 1 2 0 1]
{3 6 9}
```

z gives you the reminder whereas x is more compact since you get only the values that can be divided by 3. We call that operation slicing.

2) Then you need to SheetWrite with a range that depends on some value.

.mod

```
int n=10;

dvar int x;
string SheetWriteConnectionString;

maximize x;
subject to {
          x<=2;
}

int y[i in 1..n+1+x]=2;

execute
{
    writeln("y= ",x);
    SheetWriteConnectionString="A1:A"+n+1+x;
}
```

.dat

```
SheetConnection s("output.xlsx");
y to SheetWrite(s,SheetWriteConnectionString);
```

will achieve that.